# Why is this VBA data-fetching function hanging in Access?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, fetch

I have this function in VBA, which I have used successfully before in Excel to fetch data from a URL:

```
'========================================================
Public Function sURLfetch(ByVal sURL As String) As String
'========================================================
' Return data found at a URL.

' From "www.MyExcelGenius.com/getting-data-from-a-website-in-json-format-using-vba/".
' Requires reference "Microsoft XML, v6.0".

Const bRunAsynch As Boolean = True
Const nProcessComplete As Integer = 4

Dim oRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set oRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Dim sResponse As String

With oRequest
    .Open "get", sURL, bRunAsynch
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .send

    Do While oRequest.ReadyState <> nProcessComplete
        DoEvents
      Loop
    
    sResponse = .responseText
  End With

sURLfetch = sResponse

'========================================================
End Function        ' sURLfetch()
'========================================================
```

I am now calling this function from another function, which I am calling from a query in Access. When I do that, the call to this function hangs if I try to run it uninterrupted. But if I set a breakpoint on the line:

```
Do While oRequest.ReadyState <> nProcessComplete
```

and then tell VBA to continue, then it runs. However, if I remove that breakpoint and set a breakpoint on the line:

```
sResponse = .responseText
```

then it hangs.

So, it appears that when this function is called from Access, it hangs on the loop unless it is told to pause by a breakpoint before entering the loop.

I tried to automate the pause by inserting a call to a function that pauses VBA for a random time. That did not prevent the function from hanging.

Summary:

- The function has worked in the past in Excel.
- It works in Access if it is paused by a breakpoint at the beginning of the loop.
- It hangs if it is called in Access without that breakpoint.

What could be causing this function to hang in Access, and what could I change to get it to work?

Comment: Does that function still work in Excel or does it hang in Excel too? It's possible that the URL you're using is being unresponsive and no amount of programming is going to fix someone else's unresponsive server.

Comment: It can't be a problem with the URL because the function works with the breakpoint. With the breakpoint set, the function returns the expected content from the URL.

Comment: Does the same function currently work in Excel? Which version of Office is the last known version that this function worked properly?

Comment: It will take me some time to find the implementation in Excel. I'll look and retest it there. In the meantime, it would be great if anyone can see the problem with the code.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `Do While`? Based on your symptoms, it's just creating an infinite loop. Your code looks different than https://stackoverflow.com/a/36861855/2191572 so I would start with trying the code from the post I shared.

Comment: The purpose of the loop is to ensure that the fetching process has completed before recording the response. I have watched the operation of the code, and the loop usually repeats zero or one time. When it repeats, that means the fetch was incomplete and needed to finish. The code you linked to does not have that loop, which probably means it was accessing a shorter data stream. But the loop appears to be needed for what I am fetching. As I said, the loop is not infinite, but repeats zero or one time. But it is mysterious that it hangs if there's not a breakpoint set.

Comment: Assuming you're right, then that means `DoEvents` is holding things up.

Comment: I looked it up in my Excel code, and I was wrong. I originally wrote the code for use in Excel, but it was never implemented there. Later, since it wasn't Excel-specific, I moved the code to a module used for both Excel and Access, but never actually used it. Today, I found a need for it in Access and ran into the problem described here. But I was wrong when I said that it previously worked in Excel. Because of the attention paid here to that false statement, I've posted a new question without it: https://superuser.com/questions/1725207/why-is-this-vba-data-fetching-function-hanging

Comment: Right, so you found code on the Internet, cobbled more unknown code to it, did not test it, and now want someone else to fix it for you? If you need the request to finish before moving to the next line then why the heck are you using `bRunAsynch = true`? Make the request synchronous then `Do While` will be eliminated. Copy, paste n' pray is a terrible mindset for programming.

Comment: You're being a bit harsh on me. I'm doing the best I can to understand what I'm doing, but that's sometimes hard. But your last comment about `asynch' making the loop necessary helped me figure out the problem, and I've posted an answer to the new question explaining that and how I fixed it. So thank you.