# Why is this VBA data-fetching function hanging?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, fetch

I have written this function in VBA to fetch data from a URL. I am calling it from another function that is called in an Access query. The code is adapted from code in an article cited in the comments of the code:

```
'========================================================
Public Function sURLfetch(ByVal sURL As String) As String
'========================================================
' Return data found at a URL.

' From "www.MyExcelGenius.com/getting-data-from-a-website-in-json-format-using-vba/".
' Requires reference "Microsoft XML, v6.0".

Const bRunAsynch As Boolean = True
Const nProcessComplete As Integer = 4

Dim oRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set oRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Dim sResponse As String

With oRequest
    .Open "get", sURL, bRunAsynch
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .send

    Do While oRequest.ReadyState <> nProcessComplete
        DoEvents
      Loop
    
    sResponse = .responseText
  End With

sURLfetch = sResponse

'========================================================
End Function        ' sURLfetch()
'========================================================
```

When this function is called, it hangs VBA. But here's the strange thing: If I set a breakpoint on the line:

```
Do While oRequest.ReadyState <> nProcessComplete
```

and then tell VBA to continue from there, then it runs fine and returns the desired result. It does this over and over, returning the proper sequence of results, as long as the code is interrupted at that breakpoint and then continued. However, if I remove that breakpoint and set a breakpoint instead on the line right after the loop:

```
sResponse = .responseText
```

then it hangs and I get nothing.

So, for some reason, this function hangs on the loop unless it is told to pause by a breakpoint before entering the loop.

The purpose of the loop is to ensure that the fetching process has completed before recording the response. I have watched the operation of the code, and the loop usually repeats zero or one time. When it repeats, that means the fetch was incomplete and needed to finish. So the loop is necessary for what I am fetching. And for some reason, it appears to work okay as long as there's a breakpoint before it, but otherwise mysteriously hangs.

The `DoEvents` function, the entire contents of the loop, just tells VBA to let the operating system do whatever it has going on while the loop is executing. That function call is in the [original code](https://www.MyExcelGenius.com/getting-data-from-a-website-in-json-format-using-vba/) adapted here and there's documentation of the function by [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) and [wellsr](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-doevents-and-when-to-use-it/).

I tried to automate the pause by inserting a call to a function that pauses VBA for a random time. That did not prevent the function from hanging.

Summary:

- The function works if it is paused by a breakpoint at the beginning of the loop.
- It hangs if it is called without a breakpoint or with a breakpoint after that loop.

What could be causing this function to hang, and what could I change to get it to work?

Comment: so I think this is because vba does not handle *callbacks*, and you are using async.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this VBA data-fetching function hanging in Access?](https://superuser.com/questions/1725160/why-is-this-vba-data-fetching-function-hanging-in-access)

Comment: No, but my answer below to this question answers that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem was setting the `asynch` parameter in the `Open` command to `True`. That setting [allows the request to stop before it's finished](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms761398(v=vs.85)), which is what made the `DoEvents` loop necessary. So I tried changing that parameter to `False` and commenting out the loop. After that, the function seems to be working fine.

I don't know why the [original code](https://www.myexcelgenius.com/getting-data-from-a-website-in-json-format-using-vba/) used `asynch` = `True` and the loop. That seems to have been what made the function not work.